# How to define testacular.conf.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm facing issues to define testacular.conf.js file. I'm new to node.js and Testacular. Any suggestions will be useful. For now I have installed Node.js and I have also installed Testacular with the command `npm install -g testacular`. I have checked the version with: `testacular --version`, which shows `0.6.0`. Now my question are:

- how to define the Config file for testacular?
- where to define testacular.conf.js file

I have tried doing it with the command `testacular init` but when I choose a framework it's not letting me go down, even if I press Enter nothing happens.

If someone can help me out with some sample program or example I'll be thankful to you. I have seen few links, like:

- https://github.com/testacular/testacular/blob/master/test/client/testacular.conf.js
- https://github.com/testacular/testacular

which are also showing an error, like `LogInfo not defined` and `jasmin not defined`.

Can you please give me an example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue as well. The link (and mentioned repo) below helped to set it correctly:

http://mrforbes.com/blog/2013/02/yeoman-testacular-jquery-require-backbone-sass-mocha-dust-i18n-oh-my/